# Prevent parent CSS while focus on child button

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js, styled-components

I've a `<div>` wrapped within `<a>`. `a:active` has `css` to transform the element but I don't want that behaviour `(transform)` to be there while I focus on `bx--overflow-menu` child. I am using NextJS with styled-jsx and SaSS. Below is my code :

```
<a class="singleTile" data-cta-type="unimplemented" href="test">
   <div class="bx--row">
      <div class="bx--overflow-menu" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Menu" tabindex="0">
         <svg focusable="false" aria-label="open and close list of options" role="img" class="bx--overflow-menu__icon">
            <circle cx="8" cy="3" r="1"></circle>
            <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="1"></circle>
            <circle cx="8" cy="13" r="1"></circle>
            <title>open and close list of options</title>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="bx--col">
         <p class="name-212">cougar</p>
         <p class="name-213">Version:<span class="" style="display: inline;">test.1</span></p>
      </div>
   </div>
</a>
```

The styles:

```
<style>
.singleTile {
    flex: none;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem;
    transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9);
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
a.singleTile:hover {
    border-color: red;
}
a.singleTile:active {
    transform: scale(.994);
}
.bx--overflow-menu{
    top: 0;
    right: .25rem;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

I have some idea that it can't be done with CSS only and I am also not allowed to use jQuery. 
Any other suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

There are no parent selectors in css right now. It could be possible to implement this on next css4.

```
.singleTile:has(> bx--overflow-menu:active) { /* styles to apply to the singleTile tag */ }
```

Comment: yes, because it's impossible to select parent element with css

Comment: you need to use js